# FB graph API returns error for some public objects

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can't understand why `https://graph.facebook.com/<fbid>` returns error for some photo IDs and perfectly returns complete data for other photos:

Zuck's public photo:
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=678444210201&set=a.678443077471.2250487.4&type=3&theater

https://graph.facebook.com/678444210201 returns:

```
{
    "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100
    }
}
```

Public photo from **my** timeline:

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=477213612342669&set=a.477213729009324.114979.100001621044970&type=3&theater

Again https://graph.facebook.com/477213612342669 returns just the same error.

And now, for example, techcrunch's public photo:

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151697421107952&set=a.114456157951.118433.8062627951&type=1

https://graph.facebook.com/10151697421107952 returns complete data for the photo.

I understand that usually this error means that there are some restrictions set - user settings, application settings, etc. But I can't find in my account specific settings ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a lot of same errors.
Exitent bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/285682524881107

Just could say, that sometimes FQL query could retrieve data, SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE object_id = 477213612342669

BW your public photo (477213612342669) is working for my with my valid accessToken.

Usually, FB says that if there any privacy restriction that don't allows user to see photo, then API will return "Unsupported get request", but in this cases you could see photo with user account ... :(